# Counting frequency of customer

Tags: sql

I have this table on sql sever

```
cstomer |No_Nota
CUS000     | 98342
CUS000     | 98343
CUS000     | 98343
CUS001     | 98355
CUS001     | 98355
```

I would like to count the frequency of each customer. For similar number of no_nota the value is 1.

I'd like a result like this:

```
cstomer |Frequent
CUS000     | 2
CUS001     | 1
```

Comment: Did you already tried something? What was not working?

Comment: "please tell me the query to solve my problem above" : No, you have to search by yourself before asking. Show us your query and we will help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want the distinct count of the column `no_nota`, so that's what you should select...

```
select customer, count(distinct no_nota) as frequent
  from my_table
 group by customer
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to count the result of your select query:

```
    SELECT COUNT(expression)
    FROM tables
    WHERE predicates;
```

Example:

```
    SELECT COUNT(No_Nota) FROM your_table WHERE No_Nota > 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you just want a group by statement to get a count of all individual customers.  Something like:

```
SELECT cstomer, SUM(1) as Frequent FROM table GROUP BY cstomer, No_Nota
```